# Ansible: host_variables grouping in one file

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have a key with different value on each server(host), how can I save all those values in a single file, so that when my playbook is executed it reads from that file.

From Ansible documentation: I found under host_vars/hostname I have to create a file for each server and add the variable. It would be cumbersome if I have like 100 servers

Answer (score 0):

You can set variables by host in your inventory file like this: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#host-variables

Groups and group_vars are another solution that may be fit your requirements.