# Ansible: can host_variables be grouped in one file?

Tags: ansible

I am reasking this question because it was answered but now the link is dead.

"I have a key with different value on each server(host), how can I save all those values in a single file, so that when my playbook is executed it reads from that file.

From Ansible documentation: I found under host_vars/hostname I have to create a file for each server and add the variable. It would be cumbersome if I have like 100 servers"

[Ansible: host_variables grouping in one file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42236056/ansible-host-variables-grouping-in-one-file)

Comment: You can put those values directly in your inventory file in each host declaration. An other solution is to create a dict in a separate file which keys are your hosts, load that file in your playbook and fetch the correct key when you need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood well, you have a variable which has a different value for every single host in your inventory.

*Side note:* If you are really trying to set this up in an environment with 100 servers, it is probably time to think about a dynamic inventory since I guess those values are available out of ansible in an other information system. See [working with dynamic inventories](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html) and [developing dynamic inventories](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html).

You already found out you could set those values host by host in `host_vars/<host>.yml` files which does not suit your needs. If your requirement is to have those values declared in a single file, I see two solutions.

1. Declare the values directly in the inventory source. Here is an example for a `yaml` inventory format but you can do this for `ini` format the same way. See [adding variables to inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#adding-variables-to-inventory) for more details

   ```yaml
   ---
   all:
     hosts:
       host_a:
         my_var: abcd
     children:
       group1:
         hosts:
           host_b: 
             my_var: cdef
           host_c:
             my_var: efgh
       group2:
         hosts:
           host_d:
             my_var: ghij
   ```

   You can then get the value of that var in any playbook task running on the given target host like in the following example:

   ```yaml
   - name: host var in inventory example
     hosts: all
     gather_facts: false

     tasks:
       - name: show value of my var for target host
         debug:
           msg: "value of my_var for {{ inventory_hostname }} is: {{ my_var }}"
   ```
2. Use an external dict providing the values. Declare it in a separate file:

   ```yaml
   ---
   my_var_vals:
     host_a: abcd
     host_b: cdef
     host_c: efgh
     host_d: ghij
   ```

   You can then use that dict in any playbook and lookup the given value depending on the hostname. My example below uses `vars_files` but you could use an `include_vars` task in the same way.

   ```yaml
   ---
   - name: lookup a value in dict example
     hosts: all
     gather_facts: false

     vars_files:
       - path/to/above/dict_file.yml

     vars:
       my_var: "{{ my_var_vals[inventory_hostname] }}"

     tasks:
       - name: show value of my var for target host from dict
         debug:
           msg: "value of my_var for {{ inventory_hostname }} is: {{ my_var }}"
   ```

Answer (score -1):

As Ansible permits, you can put the vars you want to affect all the servers in `group_vars/all` file. The vars in this file will affect all servers, as many servers as you have in the inventory

Otherwise you can create groups like this example in you Inventory file:

```
---
all:
  hosts:
    localhost:
      ansible_connection: local
      ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
  children:
    target_hosts:
      hosts: 
        fedora:
        apache:
        localhost:        
      vars:
        ansible_user: vagrant
        ansible_ssh_pass: vagrant
        ansible_ssh_extra_args: '-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'
```

Also, there is a folder scheme you can use to substitute the `vars:` key on the inventory file.

For example. if you do not want to provide these vars to the group `target_hosts` inside you inventory file, you can create a file instead in `group_vars/target_hosts/main.yml` or `group_vars/target_hosts.yml`

Ansible will recognize it as vars for `target_hosts` group and will load it before executing the playbook

Plus, you can have as many groups as you want and use the way you want. Like i did with `localhost`, i've declared the variables inside the host keys and after that, added it to the group `target_hosts`

For the `fedora` and `apache`, the same vars applied to the group will be applied for them, even declared on the inventory or if you do as i said and put it in group_vars

Comment: This is a perfect explanation for setting group variables (i.e. one variable value for a given group). OP's question is basically "how can I set a different value for a variable on each single host using a unique source file (e.g. not `host_vars/<host>.yml`)?"